# Using same Javascript code for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm learning Javascript. I want to create 4 forms that will calculate the price in different number of days but the calculations are same except the price in different days. I created the forms, but I'm getting output for only the first form and not for the other forms. These are the codes.

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
 function Total(qty,ud,total,value)
 {
  qty=document.getElementById(qty);
  ud>0?qty.value++:qty.value--;
  qty.value=Math.max(qty.value,0);
  document.getElementById(total).value=qty.value*value;
 }
</script>
```

**Html Code**

**Price Calculation for 1-2 Days**

```
     <div id="purhcaseForm">
        <form id="purchase1">

          <br> Please Select Number of Pages:<br>
          <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",8);' value='-'/>
          <input type='button' name='add'onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",8);' value='+'/>
          <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
          <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
           </form>
     </div>
```

**Price Calculation for 3-4 Days**

```
        <div id="purhcaseForm">
           <form id="purchase2">

             <br> Please Select Number of Pages:<br>
             <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",-1,"total",7);' value='-'/>
             <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",7);' value='+'/>
             <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
             <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
              </form>
        </div>
```

**Price Calculation for 5-7 Days**

```
           <div id="purhcaseForm">
              <form id="purchase3">

                <br> Please Select Number of Pages:<br>
                <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",-1,"total",6);' value='-'/>
                <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",6);' value='+'/>
                <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
                <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
                 </form>
           </div>
```

**Price Calculation for 8-10 Days**

```
              <div id="purhcaseForm">
                 <form id="purchase4">

                   <br> Please Select Number of Pages:<br>
                   <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",-1,"total",5);' value='-'/>
                   <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",5);' value='+'/>
                   <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
                   <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
                    </form>
              </div>
```

Would be very grateful if someone could show me the codes in fiddle.
Is there a way to select the number of days and number of pages in one form which shows the total cost depending on the number of days and number of pages where the number of days will directly increase the price by $5 and inversely decrease the price if number of days increases?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: You should use different ids for the different forms, and iterate through the forms to get the total value.

Comment: different ids like form1, form2 and in getelementbyID in both total and qty, i add total[i] and qty[i]. Is that it? (sorry for bad english)